# Why does my second screen have a pinkish hue?

Tags: display, color

I connected my Macbook Pro to an LG 19" screen via a USB-C to HDMI adaptor, then an HDMI to VGA converter and when I turn it on it has a pinkish hue which seems to disappear randomly after a while and become normal. I have set my display color mode to Color LCD. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Cheap or poor cables. Have you tried others?

Comment: You're converting a DisplayPort signal to HDMI, then HDMI to VGA; one digital to a different digital signal, then to an analog signal.  This is bound to have issues.  Go from [USB-C directly to VGA with the correct adapter](http://radnex.us/usbc-mdp-dvi-vga-hdmi-adapter)

Comment: It worked. I bought a VGA to USB-C adapter and the issue is gone.